# I need to filter a particular column with custom filter value applied to it with Apache POI

Tags: java, apache-poi

I need to custom filter the value of a column(based on one of the values of the column) after applying the auto-filter.

The below method helps me to apply autofilter for the columns A3 through E3

```
sheet.setAutoFilter(CellRangeAddress.valueOf("A3:E3"));
```

But if I use the same method for custom filtering, like below. It doesn't work.
In this case, I want to filter the rows for the value of column E3 as "Near End"

```
sheet.setAutoFilter(CellRangeAddress.valueOf("E3:Near End"));
```

It did not work and throws - java.lang.IllegalArgumentException error.

I tried to use the HSSFAutoFilter class like below, with method 'equals'. It also did not work.

```
HSSFAutoFilter autofilter;
autofilter = sheet.setAutoFilter(CellRangeAddress.valueOf("E3"));
autofilter.equals("Near End");
```

Have seen on a website saying:

```
AutoFilter filter = 
sheet.setAutoFilter(CellRangeAddress.valueOf("A1:F200"));
filter.applyFilter(0, "apache", "poi", "java", "api");
```

But the "appyfilter()" option doesn't seem to to be available now.

I am using the poi 3.8 JAR files.